# Trouble creating a "speed dial" button on Android

Tags: android, dialog

I'm making a very simple launcher for Android. I'm having trouble getting some speed dial buttons to work.

The idea is that when the user presses the speed dial buttons for the first time, they'll be prompted to enter a phone number with a popup window (dialog? I think?). That number will then be assigned to that button, which will then call the assigned number when the button is next pressed. It's not great if they want to reassign a number, but this is just something rough that i'd like to get out of the way. I'm thinking of creating an int to reflect the state of the button (0 = no number assigned, 1 = number is assigned), and using if statements to either bring up the window or call the number.

I don't know how to bring up such a window (although I do know I can bring up a dial pad using (android:inputType="phone")), as well as how to pass the number that the user inputted to an int/long. I'm thinking I can assign the value to an int, although that might not be the most optimal data type. I have a rough idea on how to dial a number once it's given.

What should I do? I'm quite new to programming, so i'm having trouble with this.

Answer (score 0):

may be this could help.

1. have a long click listener to the buttons.
2. on long click event, show a dialog widow which accepts the number.
3. store it in a persistent memory, either db, files or pref utils by android.
4. in on click button, have a logic to retrieve the stored content and update the views accordingly.